# how to bind menuitem to another project in same solution

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

There are  two projects in one solution,How to bind a web page(.aspx) for Navigate URL property in menu item in different project.I need to access menu item in one project to another project aspx page.
I cannot able to do this by choosing in pick url

how to access other project webpage(.aspx) from different project.I want to navigate to a page in different project from asp:menu. the two projects are in same solution. NavigateURL="~***" i am using if it is in same project and i need to map the webpage in different project

Comment: Try write this URL yourself...

Comment: you can have multiple webprojects in your solution, but you can launch only one of them at a time in visual studio, others are simply not hosted. you cannot access

Comment: how to access other project webpage(.aspx) from different project.I want to navigate  to a page in different project from asp:menu. the two projects are in same solution.
NavigateURL="~\***"  i am using if it is in same project and i need to map the webpage in different project

Comment: @Manish, that's not entirely correct because the solution can be configured to launch more than one project and both can be web projects.

Comment: @Anand, you're just not explaining yourself very well. When you say access from another project, is this a web project or a class library? Is this menu item part of a UserControl?

Comment: it is a web project and i am using menu control in asp.net

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that if you referring a page from the same website (in your case a project in the solution) then you can give a relative URL. Like

> Myfolder/abc.aspx

OR

> ~/Myfolder/abc.aspx

***Relative URL** : Relative URLs are more convenient because they are shorter and often more portable. However, you can use them only to reference links on the same server as the page that contains them.*

In case of a page outside your project (In your case another project in the same solution) you need to give absolute url like

```
http://myserver/mysite/abc.aspx
```

***Absolute URL :** An absolute URL contains all the information necessary to locate a resource.*

Please note **“~”** is only used with relative URL not with the absolute URL.

While doing the actual deployment you will require hosting them as tow separate websites, but while developing you can still run two websites/applications simultaneously using the solution configuration “Start-up Project”  option as multiple and by fixing the port in the configuration of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

***Use This :***

```
string Path = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
       VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/");
```

Path will contain your current localhost/CurrentOpenedProject, replace it by Project required
by using :

```
   Path = Path.Replace("CurrentOpenedProject", "RequiredProject");
```

You can add this to menuItem like this:

```
   for(int i = 0; i < Menu1.Items.Count;i++){
        Menu1.Items[i].NavigateUrl = Path;
    }
```

Comment: How to set this for menu control in the nagationurl property

Comment: Edited Post,feel free to ask anything else and pleace add +1 :D

Comment: i want to do bind this in designer(.aspx) page not in (.aspx.cs) page